# Python, IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python, строки, индексация

Не понимаю как исправить ошибку. При вводе aaaabbcaa должно появиться `a4b2c1a2`, но появляется `a4bbcaa` и ошибка:

```
line 10, in <module>
    if gen[j]==gen[i]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

---

```
gen=input()
l=len(gen)-1

for i in range(0,l):
  chs=1
  if gen[i]==int:
    continue

  for j in range(i+1,l+1):
    if gen[i]==chs:
      continue
    if gen[j]==gen[i]:
      chs+=1
    elif gen[j]!=gen[i]:
      s=gen[i:j]
      s=s.replace(s[i:j],s[i]+str(chs))
      gen=s+gen[j:l+1]
      continue
print(gen)
```

Comment: У вас индекс j выходит за пределы длины, введенной строки gen (см. range(i+1, l+1)), поэтому косяк

Comment: `print(''.join(x[1]+str(len(x[0])) for x in re.findall(r'((.)\2*)', gen)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать подобный алгоритм для преобразования строки

```
>>> gen = "aaaabbcaa"
>>> res = []
>>> for c in gen:
...   if res and c == res[-1][0]:
...     res[-1][1] += 1
...   else:
...     res += [[c, 1]]
...
>>> ''.join(''.join(str(elem) for elem in sub) for sub in res)
'a4b2c1a2'
```

Т.е. код будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
gen = input()
res = []
for c in gen:
  if res and c == res[-1][0]:
    res[-1][1] += 1
  else:
    res += [[c, 1]]
print(''.join(''.join(str(elem) for elem in sub) for sub in res))
```

---

## UPD

Проблема вашего кода заключается в том, что вы изменяете строку `gen`, а значит, изменяется и её длина, в то время как у вас циклы идут по статичной длине изначальной строки. Чтобы проверить это, запустите этот код и убедитесь в результате:

```
trace = lambda: print(f'l = {l}; chs = {chs}; i = {i}; j = {j};\n\t\ts = {s}; gen = {gen}')
gen = 'aaaabbcaa'
l=len(gen)-1
j = None
s = ''

for i in range(0,l):
  chs=1
  trace()
  if gen[i]==int:
    continue

  for j in range(i+1,l+1):
    trace()
    if gen[i]==chs:
      continue
    if gen[j]==gen[i]:
      chs+=1
    elif gen[j]!=gen[i]:
      s=gen[i:j]
      s=s.replace(s[i:j],s[i]+str(chs))
      gen=s+gen[j:l+1]
      continue
print(gen)
```

Как видно по последнему удачному выводу переменных, длина строки `gen` равна 7, т.е. последний индекс в ней - 6, а в переменной `j` находится число 7. Отсюда и исключение

```
l = 8; chs = 1; i = 0; j = None;
        s = ; gen = aaaabbcaa
l = 8; chs = 1; i = 0; j = 1;
        s = ; gen = aaaabbcaa
l = 8; chs = 2; i = 0; j = 2;
        s = ; gen = aaaabbcaa
l = 8; chs = 3; i = 0; j = 3;
        s = ; gen = aaaabbcaa
l = 8; chs = 4; i = 0; j = 4;
        s = ; gen = aaaabbcaa
l = 8; chs = 4; i = 0; j = 5;
        s = a4; gen = a4bbcaa
l = 8; chs = 5; i = 0; j = 6;
        s = a4; gen = a4bbcaa
l = 8; chs = 6; i = 0; j = 7;
        s = a4; gen = a4bbcaa
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
    if gen[j]==gen[i]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет, но я, судя по всему, не точно выразился, мне также важна причина ошибки, чтобы не допускать её вновь.

Comment: @Какой-тоNoname обновил ответ. Думаю, теперь он отвечает на ваш вопрос полностью =)

Comment: Благодарю за уточнения)